# Files on SMB share not writable by "some" applications

Tags: networking, file-permissions, smb

I have a problem with a shared network drive where, in principle, I can create and modify files, but some applications give an `incorrect function` error (or similar) when trying to modify a file on that network drive.

Say, for example, that there is a `test.txt` file on this network share. If this file is opened in notepad or VS code then this file can be modified, but if this file is modified using sublime text or helix then the application returns an `incorrect function` error.

It does seem that this problem only pops up when trying to modify an existing file. Writing new files to the network share doesn't seem to cause any problems (in the programs I've tested).

(This issue also shows in certain other programs which try to modify a file in a propiatory format, for which there isn't an alternative program to edit the file).

Answer (score 0):

The difference might relate to the way that the program is saving the
file after editing it.

Some editors write a new file with a temporary name, delete the old file,
then rename the new file to the old name.

Other editors just directly overwrite the target file.
I would guess that the problem is with these editors.

It seems like the share permissions allow you to create new files, delete
files and rename files. The permissions apparently do not let you modify
existing files.

We would need more information on this network share in order to point
to one particular lacking in its permissions.